# How to describe the walk of a man with an artificial leg?

Tags: word-request

How to describe the walk of a man with an artificial leg? People with artificial legs don't walk in the same way as a normal person. What are non-offensive words that can be used to describe their walk?

Comment: Describe "the walk of a man with an artificial leg" to what audience? Are you talking to his doctor? Is he a fictional character in a book? Are you describing him in a police report? These different contexts could influence the answer considerably.

Comment: Not both. Just to describe in a story when the character first appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, a person with an artificial leg often walks with a ***jerky*** gait. Sometimes it might be better described as a ***stiff*** gait, but the general principle would be that so long as whatever you put in front of *gait* doesn't have too many offensive connotations, just use any normal word that fits the particular person's way of walking (it will vary, obviously).

> [The artificial leg gave Carl a jerky gait, but he moved with a deliberate air.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22but%20who%20helped%20us%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22artificial%20leg%22%20%22jerky%20gait%22&oq=%22artificial%20leg%22%20%22jerky%20gait%22&gs_l=serp.3...6341.8933.2.9553.11.11.0.0.0.1.186.884.9j2.11.0....0...1c.1.23.psy-ab..24.0.0.apSxQgOVns0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=c74fb9c2dbf5756c&biw=1369&bih=911&bvm=pv.xjs.s.en_US.seW1cfrvSKg.O)

You might get away with saying they walk with a *slight limp*, but *limp* isn't normally a very positive word.

Comment: Got it. How does the following sentence look? He walks with a stiff hobbling gait since one of his legs is artificial.

Comment: @T2E: I'd avoid _artificial_. Try something more like this: _Because of his prosthetic leg, he walks with a stiff hobbling gait_. You can also use _prosthesis_ if you'd prefer to shorten it to one word.

Comment: I totally disagree that the word "limp" is in any way negative. If it's accurate, use it. If it's not accurate, don't use it.

Comment: @J.R. What is the reason, you are suggesting to avoid the word 'artificial'? I see prosthetic means artificial body part. Can you please tell me the reason?

Comment: @T2E: I imagine J.R. is influenced by the fact that *prosthetic* is a relatively "clinical" term [(far less well-known than *artificial leg*)](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=artificial+leg%2Cprosthetic+leg&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). Someone else upvoted the comment, so obviously there are at least two people who think *artificial* has negative connotations here, but I don't think most people would take that position.

Comment: I agree with @Martha, in that, if it was my walk you were describing, I'd probably bristle at "jerky" before "limp." The more this conversation transpires, though, the more I realize how little context is given in the O.P.'s question. Describe _how_? In a book? To a doctor? To a friend? What constitutes "polite" or "impolite" can often vary a little bit according to context; some contexts require more careful wording than others.

Comment: @J.R.: I agree that the question is woefully lacking in context. But I figured that whatever *adjective* is appropriate in any given context (both semantically, and in terms of positive/negative connotations), the noun ***gait*** is likely to be useful. But I found quite a few references to *jerky gait* in "medical/therapeutic" contexts in Google Books. So it strikes me as probably an accurate term for use at the professional level, where it's presumably not considered "derogatory" (it can hardly avoid being *negative* by the very nature of the referent).

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to go ahead and post this as an answer: the correct word to use for describing how someone with a limp walks is, guess what: **limp**.

As J.R. mentioned, anything that is more graphic — such as *jerky* — is much more likely to come across as, well, maybe not outright *offensive*, but certainly approaching it. This isn't because *jerky* is an offensive word (it's not - there's a world of difference between "word that describes an unpleasant concept" and "offensive word"), but because it's not the usual, everyday word one expects to hear in such a context. It calls attention to a defect, rather than merely describing it.

(I've never been quite sure what a *rolling gait* is supposed to look like, but I do know it's most often used for someone who spends most of his time in a boat, and thus has a hard time adapting his gait to dry land. It does not, to me, imply any unevenness or lopsidedness; whereas for most people with prosthetic legs, the defining feature of their gait is the fact that one of their legs is not like the other.)

Comment: I like 'stiff gait'.

Answer (score 2):

[**Hobble**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hobble?s=t) is also an alternative. Like *limp* it is understood by the majority of native and non-native speakers. I might also use the word *after* I've banged my toe against something hard, and instinctively hop around the room. Later, if my big toe is still hurting, I would hobble about.

Comment: *Hobble* implies (much) less mobility than *limp*, but there are certainly cases where it's the more descriptive word.

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes described as a *rolling gait*:

> That and the stick he used and the slow, [rolling gait](http://books.google.com/books?ei=W_7-UeH_IeTAigLTj4CICA&id=w5YiAQAAIAAJ&q=%22rolling+gait%22) of a man who made do with an artificial leg after an above-the-knee amputation meant no one near him said a word about it.

Comment: *Rolling gait* is a specific description of how a specific man walked because of an artificial leg. It's by no means a general description of how everyone who has an artificial leg walks.

Answer (score 0):

A fancy, politically correct term for a person who walks artificially would be "orthopedically, challenged."

Comment: 1. I don't think anyone would ever use that except if they were being facetious. 2. This describes the person, not the way they walk.